# How do I create collapsable edittext areas similar to the attachment in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Thanks for reading this, I would like to create a collapsable edittext content area in my android activity and I don't know how to do it. see the screenshot below
when the user clicks a particular view containing the edittext, an edittext appears and is only hidden when the user clicks the view again.
[image: id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KOTLIN

```
 text.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                if(text_layout.visibility == View.VISIBLE)
                    text_layout.visibility = View.GONE
                else
                    text_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            })
```

use Visiblity to handle that

JAVA

```
text = findViewById(R.id.text);
text_layout = findViewById(R.id.text_layout);
text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(text_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    text_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                else
                    text_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

XML

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello asdasdasd!"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/text_layout"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#000"/>
```

Comment: Wow. this is such a simple solution, I am soo embarrassed..  :) Thanks so much, pal

Comment: @MIikeEps see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on other SO which still don't have answers.